# Spelling check for tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just wondering if it is possible to have a new feature to have perform spelling check on tags.

Suppose I tag a question using this tag 'Infpath' (yes, I know that it is a spelling mistake as there is a missing 'o'), the web application will recommend the correct term - 'Infopath'.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be difficult to come up with a comprehensive spell checker that could keep up with technical terms and product names.

The tags are basically a managed folksonomy. I think the best spell checker is having observant users of the site who are willing to edit the tags that have been miss-spelled.

Comment: Plus we already have the tag auto-complete feature... shouldn't that help with most spelling errors?